# sending an image to client through sockets won't work python

Tags: python, networking, server, client

I am new to python programming and networking. trying to learn.
I'm trying to send a screenshot from server computer to client.
saving the screenshot on server works but saving it after sending it on client side won't work.
Any help would be amazing. I wasn't able to fix it through other solutions I found in similar questions.
server code:

```
    if (command == 'TAKE_SCREENSHOT'):
        img = open(r'C:\Cyber\screen.jpg', 'rb').read()
        print(len(img))
        client_socket.send(img)
```

and client code is:

```
from PIL import Image
    data = my_socket.recv(2048)
    buff = StringIO(data.decode(errors='ignore'))
    img = Image.open(buff.encoding)
    img.save(r'C:\Client\newscreen.jpg')
```

Comment: Try buff.seek(0) before opening it. Or try BytesIO. Howevrr the seek is required in both cases.

Comment: Hey, tried it and I get this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Also you are receiving just 2048 bytes, did you mean to do that?

Comment: you are right! used BytesIO and increased the recv size and now it works! THANKS! rookie mistakes sorry

Comment: You're welcome! I believe there is even better approach (iterate chunks from recv until nothing comes out).